# VBA using DateSerial stops at blank cell in range

Tags: vba, date-formatting

I have some vba code that evaluates 6 columns and formats the dates from yyyymmdd to mm/dd/yyyy. The code works fine until it finds a blank cell within the range and then I get a type 13 Run time error. The debugger highlights the DateSerial line so I assume thats where my issue is.

Any thoughts?

```
Sub Convert_Date()
    Dim c As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each c In Range("AC2:AC" & Cells(Rows.Count, "AC").End(xlUp).Row)
        c.Value = DateSerial(Left(c.Value, 4), Mid(c.Value, 5, 2), Right(c.Value, 2))
        c.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

     Dim b As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each b In Range("AL2:AL" & Cells(Rows.Count, "AL").End(xlUp).Row)
        b.Value = DateSerial(Left(b.Value, 4), Mid(b.Value, 5, 2), Right(b.Value, 2))
        b.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

      Dim a As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each a In Range("AQ2:AQ" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
        a.Value = DateSerial(Left(a.Value, 4), Mid(a.Value, 5, 2), Right(a.Value, 2))
        a.NumberFormat = "mm/yyyy"
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim d As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each d In Range("AR2:AR" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
        d.Value = DateSerial(Left(d.Value, 4), Mid(d.Value, 5, 2), Right(d.Value, 2))
        d.NumberFormat = "mm/yyyy"
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim e As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each e In Range("AT2:AT" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
        e.Value = DateSerial(Left(e.Value, 4), Mid(e.Value, 5, 2), Right(e.Value, 2))
        e.NumberFormat = "mm/yyyy"
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

     Dim f As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each f In Range("AU2:AU" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
        f.Value = DateSerial(Left(f.Value, 4), Mid(f.Value, 5, 2), Right(f.Value, 2))
        f.NumberFormat = "mm/yyyy"
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False


End Sub
```

Comment: try: `If Not IsEmpty(c) then c.Value = DateSerial(Left(c.Value, 4), Mid(c.Value, 5, 2), Right(c.Value, 2))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to make a check around each condition, whether the value is not empty. Like this:

```
If Not IsEmpty(c) then
    c.Value = DateSerial(Left(c.Value, 4), Mid(c.Value, 5, 2), Right(c.Value, 2))
    c.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
End If
```

---

Once you get deeper into VBA, you may start using functions like this:

```
Sub Convert_Date()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    RockAndRoll "AC2:AC", "AC"
    Call RockAndRoll ("AR2:AR", "A")
    RockAndRoll "AL2:AL", "AC"
    'RockAndRoll etc...
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Public Sub RockAndRoll(myLeft As String, myRight As String)

    Dim a As Range

    With ActiveSheet
        For Each a In .Range(myLeft & .Cells(.Rows.Count, myRight).End(xlUp).Row)
            If Not IsEmpty(a) Then
                a.value = DateSerial(Left(a.value, 4), Mid(a.value, 5, 2), Right(a.value, 2))
                a.NumberFormat = "mm/yyyy"
            End If
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

So you should not be repeating the code over and over again.

Comment: Hopefully not with the `Call` statements though ;)

Comment: @CallumDA - Why, without them I have to remove the brackets?

Comment: IF NOT IsEmpty function works perfect...however, if the entire range is blank I still get a Type 13 Run Time Error...any thoughts?

Comment: The `Call` statement isn't really considered good practice. You get used to using brackets for Subs/Functions that return something -- e.g. to fill a variable/ set an object. This practice is the opposite of that. For example, you wouldn't write `Call MsgBox("test")` just so you can use brackets.

Comment: @CallumDA it makes sense indeed. Can you show some links for those good practices?